# How to print results of matched numbers with a space

Tags: java

Just thought of a simple program to practice java coding and am stuck at the end part.,..

the code prints out the required answer (what numbers match from input compared to results for a 5 number lottery) but the answer is printed without spaces.  I thought perhaps to add a "" when += to matchingNumbers but that didnt do anything!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class LottoChecker
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] yourNumbers = new int [5];
        int yourInput, resultsInput;
        int [] results = new int [5];
        int currentNumber = 0;
        String matchingNumbers = "";
        for (int i=0; i<yourNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter your main numbers: " );
            yourInput = in.nextInt();
            yourNumbers[i]=yourInput;
        }

        for (int j=0; j<results.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the results from the main numbers: ");
            resultsInput = in.nextInt();
            results[j] = resultsInput;
        }

        System.out.println("Your Numbers: " + 
Arrays.toString(bubbleSort(yourNumbers)));
        System.out.println("The Results are: " + 
Arrays.toString(results));

        for (int i =0; i<yourNumbers.length;i++)
        {
            currentNumber = yourNumbers[i];
            for (int j=0;j<results.length;j++)
                if (currentNumber == results[j])

                    matchingNumbers += currentNumber + "";

        }

        System.out.println("Your matching numbers are: " + 
matchingNumbers);

    }

    public static int [] bubbleSort(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
                { 

                    int temp = arr[j]; 
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                    arr[j+1] = temp; 
                } 
        return arr;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Try adding `" "` instead of `""`. `""` is an empty `String`

Comment: Use `"Your matching numbers are:"` and then `+= " " + currentNumber`

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution would be using [StringJoiner(" ")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) and then add the numbers on each iteration.